# How does gulp resolve dependencies before running?

Tags: gulp

Assumed there are four tasks 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' (b depends on c and d; both c and d depend on a), so tasks are run in the following order:

a-> (c, d) -> b

Here's the gulpfile.js which works accordingly:

```
gulp.task('a');
gulp.task('c', ['a']);
gulp.task('d', ['a']);
gulp.task('b', ['c', 'd']);
```

In spite of task 'c' and 'd' both depend on task 'a', gulp is smart enough to have task 'a' run only once. I'm wondering since tasks run with maximum concurrency, how does gulp resolve dependencies before running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to document it is "gulp (orchestrator) runs with maximum **possible** concurrency after accounting for all specified dependencies."

So in your scenario, do c and d actually run "in parallel"?  Well, yes and no.  Because JavaScript is single threaded, technically the processor is doing either c or d but not both.  Gulp (orchestrator) will launch a, wait for it to finish, then launch both c and d, and wait for both to finish, then launch b.

If tasks c and d are at all asynchronous, you'll see both execute simultaneously.  (Note the gulp timing outputs get intertwined.)  If the tasks are completely synchronous, technically they won't run "in parallel" ... only because JavaScript is single threaded.

It's the maximum **possible** concurrency, accounting for all your specified restrictions.

Comment: I found a gulp issue addressed the related question quite well, for anyone has similar question, you can refer to robrich's answer in https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/96.

Answer (score 2):

<del>gulp tasks don't seem to always run with maximum concurrency if tasks have dependencies.</del> [gulp's documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support) says:

> **Note**: By default, tasks run with maximum concurrency -- e.g. it
>   launches all the tasks at once and waits for nothing. If you want to
>   create a series where tasks run in a particular order, you need to do
>   two things:
>
> - give it a hint to tell it when the task is done,
> - and give it a hint that a task depends on completion of another.

gulp uses [orchestrator](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator) to run tasks and orchestrator uses [sequencify](https://github.com/robrich/sequencify) to arrange tasks in sequence.

For example, the tasks in your example will be arranged to `a -> c -> d -> b` or `a -> d -> c -> b` by sequencify and executed in sequence by orchestrator.

<del>If I understand correctly, c and d could be executed in parallel in theory but not with the current implementation of gulp.</del>

**EDIT**

orchestrator seems to run c and d in parallel. It loops through the tasks in sequence and runs tasks that are not done or running and whose dependencies are all done. It repeats that when each task is done until all tasks are done. See `Orchestrator.prototype._runStep` for more detail.

Comment: I found the code in your pointed direction. Thanks very much. :)